# Chrome and Firefox are not displaying most PDF documents in an iframe

Tags: firefox, pdf, google-chrome, iframe

I am running Windows 7, 64 bit. I have recently updated my OS to install the latest updates. Since then, most PDF documents have stopped rendering in my program. My program wants to display PDF documents in a separate iFrame. I do this by getting the URL of the PDF document and setting `window.frames['docview'].location = url;` In most cases, the iframe view remains blank (or clears if something was shown there previously). If I take that same URL and open it in a new tab or window, it renders fine.

When it fails to render in my iframe,  I see the following message in the Chrome console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf.
```

Firefox does not offer a message of any kind in its error console, or on the FireBug console.

I have no control over the source of the PDF files, so I cannot change their header information.

Oddly, some files do load correctly.

Looking at the network requests in Chrome, for a document that fails to load I see (for example):

```
Request URL:http://es.csiro.au/pubs/paradis_mdm03.pdf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:es.csiro.au
Referer:http://querium.fxpal.net:8080/querium/ui/query?searcherId=2&compact=true&sidx=rank&topicId=2&queryId=1&lastEventId=1490893682130103&highlight=undefined
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.220 Safari/535.1

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:71764
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Tue, 06 Sep 2011 04:59:26 GMT
ETag:"1f48c8-11854-43e4ee482ef40"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Last-Modified:Wed, 07 Nov 2007 04:07:49 GMT
Server:Apache/2.0.55 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.1.2 mod_ssl/2.0.55 OpenSSL/0.9.8a
```

When opened from a separate tab (where the document does render), I get the following:

```
Request URL:http://es.csiro.au/pubs/paradis_mdm03.pdf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:es.csiro.au
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 07 Nov 2007 04:07:49 GMT
If-None-Match:"1f48c8-11854-43e4ee482ef40"
Range:bytes=0-71763
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.220 Safari/535.1

Response Headers
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Tue, 06 Sep 2011 05:07:15 GMT
ETag:"1f48c8-11854-43e4ee482ef40"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache/2.0.55 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.1.2 mod_ssl/2.0.55 OpenSSL/0.9.8a
```

One odd things is the difference in status, but maybe the server is being smart or there is some funny interaction with the cache. Who knows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Gene

EDITED: 9/6/2011

When I removed the tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

from the `<head>` element of my HTML page, many (but not all) of the PDFs started rendering properly. This was an apparent duplicate of another meta tag in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Does this help shed any light on the potential problem?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `src` attribute of the iframe to the PDF, set it to a wrapper HTML-file, which contains a simple div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;">
    <div id="divContents" style="height:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In javascript the contents of the `div` is set to an `object` element. Unfortunately slightly different versions are needed to work reliable on all browsers (tested on IE, Firefox and Chrome):

*(I simplified the retrieval of the divContents element and the browser detection)*

```
var embed = '<object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"';
if (msie) {
    embed += '><param name="src" value="' + pdf + '"/>';
}
else if (chrome) {
    embed += ' src="' + pdf + '">';
}
else {
    embed += ' data="' + pdf + '">';
}
embed += '</object>';
$("#divContents").html(embed);
```

**UPDATED**

I've finally found the actual cause of the failure in Chrome: It's the `Accept-Ranges:bytes` field, without it Chrome will not work when the `data` attribute is used.

- So if your server is capable of supporting the `Accept-Ranges` field, you should make sure it is returned to the client. In that case you can use the [pdfobject](http://www.pdfobject.com/) library to display the PDF in a frame or div.
- If not, you can use the code above to display the PDF in a frame or div.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at this strategy when I get back to that project.

Answer (score 0):

In the past a few issues has been reported with pdf loaded in iframes, both for Firefox and Chrome (in particular when headers like Content-Type and Content-Disposition are not properly set).

Probably you should use an `<object>` tag to embed a pdf in your page, instead of an iframe, but an easier solution is the **[pdfobject](http://www.pdfobject.com/)** library. To verify this works, **you can browse [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9zWf/)** with Chrome and Firefox.

Moreover, you can use a **proxy script** in your server to stream the PDFs: your page will point to the proxy script and pass an identifier (so that it won't be hacked easily) and the script will download and send to the browser the matching pdf with the proper headers.

Finally a note about the different status codes: in the first response the server has sent to the browser the `Last-Modified` and the `ETag` that contains a timestamp and a hash of the file; thus the browser, in the second request ask for the resourse only

```
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 07 Nov 2007 04:07:49 GMT
If-None-Match:"1f48c8-11854-43e4ee482ef40"
```

Since the resource has not be changed, the second response is a 304.

Comment: The pdfobject library is in essence nothing more than this line of code: `targetNode.innerHTML = '<object    data="' +url +'" type="application/pdf" width="' +width +'" height="' +height +'"></object>';`. Unfortunately this doesn't work in Chrome (see my answer).

Comment: @mhu Your example might work or not, but I think you're a bit ungenerous with PDFObject, since **it supports Chrome perfectly**. Try to visit the [examples](http://pdfobject.com/examples/index.php) with Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Mmm... you don't **need** the iframe if you use PDFObject. Can you share the html you are using (eg via pastebin or jsfiddle)?

Comment: I need the iframe in my project. See my answer for the html. If you use the data-attribute in this case, the PDF doesn't show in Chrome, but using the src-attribute is does.

Comment: @mhu your answer does not contains iframes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28294/discussion-between-giacomo-tesio-and-mhu)

Comment: @mhu take a look here: jsfiddle.net/y9zWf
if you run it with chrome, you will get the pdf in the output iframe

Comment: It's the `Accept-Ranges:bytes` field, without it Chrome will not work when the `data` attribute is used, see my updated answer. I'll grand you the bounty, because testing your example against different servers gave me the insight.